# cross compile numpy for windows

Tags: python, numpy, cross-compiling, mingw32, toolchain

Is it possible to cross compile numpy for windows on a linux machine?

I've tried downloading the tarball from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy

Then install the mingw toolchain on a Fedora and giving the command:

```
python setup.py install build --compiler=mingw32
```

But it fails with error:

```
gcc -mdll -O -Wall -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python2.7 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/core/src/npymath/halffloat.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npymath/halffloat.o
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mdll'; did you mean '-Wall'?
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mdll'; did you mean '-Wall'?
error: Command "gcc -mdll -O -Wall -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python2.7 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/core/src/npymath/halffloat.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npymath/halffloat.o" failed with exit status 1
```

Which looks like it cannot pick the right compiler

Did someone succeded?

I've uploaded the whole log here:
https://pastebin.com/raw/FqxPk5Aw

Comment: Why not use the wheels from pypi or http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ ?  The latter uses the Intel math libraries, so it might be faster, depending on your processor.

Comment: I do not want to run into linker problems by mixing different compiler dlls. I would like to have the same toolchain for the whole software I'mm working on (which includes Qt fftw pythonqt and a bunch of other libraries)

Comment: Are you compiling your own Python as well?  The released Python for Windows is compiled with the MSFT toolchain, so a mingw numpy would be a mixed environment unless you do.  The lfd site has many packages built with the MSFT tools; it has everything I need, including Qt.